# How to set headers and content-type in android using jackson library (this restful .net web api)

Tags: android, jackson

This is .Net web api uri is http://sampleurlapi...../userRegistration/

if using post method JSON

```
try {
                JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
                jsonobj.put("ResNo", -1);
                jsonobj.put("DateCreated", "12-12-2015");
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < finalSelectedArrayList.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject resobject = new JSONObject();
                    resobject.put("StySK", finalSelectedArrayList.get(i).getParentSK());
                    resobject.put("TwrSK", finalSelectedArrayList.get(i).getTwrSK());
                    resobject .put("BlkSK", finalSelectedArrayList.get(i).getBlkSK());
                    resobject.put("FlrSK", finalSelectedArrayList.get(i).getFlrSK());
                    resobject.put("AptSK", finalSelectedArrayList.get(i).getAptSK());
                    resobject.put("IsDftUt", finalSelectedArrayList.get(i).getDefaultKey());
                    resobject .put(resobject);
                }
```

// make web service connection

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            // Build JSON string

            StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
            request.setEntity(entity);
            // Send request to service
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            // Get the status of web service
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            //If the result is returned as NULL, then make the validation to fail.
            if ((strValidationResult = rd.readLine()) == null) {
                strValidationResult = Boolean.FALSE.toString();
            }
```

I have Write JSON Like these.

how write json using jackson and set content-type and accept type?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The Request set header like this problem is service side only
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i don't know what you ask but i consumed .net service this way


method calling here         
int i = getconnect(email, pass);


get connect method 


public Integer getconnect(String id, String pass) {
        String result = null;
        String i = null;
        int statusCode=400;
        String r="0";
        String m="";
        int s=0;

          try {

                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url2);
                request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                // Build JSON string
                JSONStringer item = new JSONStringer()
                        .object()
                        .key("password").value(pass)
                        .key("username").value(email)
                        .endObject();
                StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(item.toString());

                request.setEntity(entity);

                // Send request to WCF service
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
                HttpEntity entity1 = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity1.getContent();
                r = convertStreamToString(stream);
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(r);
                s=  (Integer) jo.get("Flag");
                Log.d("json result is:", r);
            statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            Log.d("error", "code"+0);
        }
        return s;
    }
    public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

Comment: I know  how do in normal Json i am ask how to write using jackson library

Comment: may be it will help you i don't know about jackson processor                                                                                                                                                                                     https://capdroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/android-simple-json-parsing-using-jackson-apis/